Ошибка Time Limit Exceeded на leet code
Написал решение для задачи 2623. Memoize (Medium):


function memoize(fn) {
    const cachedArgs = {};

    return function(...args) {
        const filterNameForArgs = args.join(".");

        if (Object.keys(cachedArgs).includes(filterNameForArgs)) {
            return cachedArgs[filterNameForArgs];
        }

        const resultOfFunction = fn(...args);
        cachedArgs[filterNameForArgs] = resultOfFunction;

        return resultOfFunction;
    }
}



но при проверке получаю такую ошибку, что нужно обновить в коде для его ускорения?

спасиб, совсем забыл)

Object.keys(cachedArgs).includes(filterNameForArgs) это очень плохо. Вы идёте по всех ключам объекта, что бы создать из них массив, а потом идёте по всем элементам массива что бы проверить равенство. Итого два полных перебора и лишнее создание массива. У объектов есть специальный метод для проверки ключа Object.hasOwn.

Добавь ссылку на задачу в leetcode

https://leetcode.com/problems/memoize/description/
